How can i make it work correctly?(python, TeleBot code)
i was trying to make telegram bot that will be resending messages to bot owner and when i tested it for 1st time it worked correctly, but then i changed something, saved and it broken. Bot now sending 2 messages instead of 1 as it should, why and how to fix that?
here's the code:
import telebot
BOT_TOKEN= 'token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тест бота.')
@bot.message_handler()
def reply(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
    bot.send_message(owner_id, message.text)
#———————————————

bot.infinity_polling()

i was trying do everything with 1 message handler but it seemed like not working correctly
for example it should work like this:
User --> Message --> Bot;
Bot --> Message --> User(for test),Owner;

but it works like that:
User --> Message --> Bot;
Bot --> Message --> User(for test),Owner; (its being repeated so user and owner are getting 2 messages instead of 1)


Comment this line bot.send_message(owner_id, message.text) and say what happens.

bot sends to user(thats just for test) and owner 2 mesages, for example: user input 1 message, 'hello' and bot will send 2 'hello' to user and owner, but it should send only 1 message

For your next question, try to write a more descriptive title. See [ask].

Personally, it works as it should for me. Are you by any chance not checking this as the owner? Because the bot will always forward his messages to him.
Here is the code that fixes it :
import telebot

BOT_TOKEN = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

owner_id = ""

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тест бота.')
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def reply(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
    if int(message.from_user.id) != int(owner_id):
        bot.send_message(owner_id, message.text)
#———————————————

bot.infinity_polling()


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
